# Conditional execution inside JSP in Stripes

Tags: jsp, stripes

I want to test against the value of n actionBean variable and print different messages based on the results. My code right now is:

```
<% if ( ${actionBean.server.virtual} == true ) { %>
This is a virtual machine.<br/>
<% } else { %>
This is not a virtual machine.<br/>
<% } %>
```

The `actionBean` has a function `getServer()` which returns an object that has a `getVirtual()` function that return a Boolean.

The code is (obviously) not working - I didn't really expect it to, but I haven't been able to find documentation combining the "access an actionBean" part with the "conditional execution" part with the "inside the Stripes framework" part. I don't want to just do

```
Virtual machine? ${actionBean.server.virtual}<br/>
```

Even though I know this will work, it's not very human-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing a Java scriptlet with JSTL.  Choose JSTL and use the jsp core taglib.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--Your jsp should start with the taglib declaration above.--%>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${actionBean.server.virtual}">
        This is a virtual machine.<br/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        This is not a virtual machine.<br/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - works like a charm! (This is partly why sysadmins should never be let anywhere near Java code.)